# SharePoint REST api Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: list, rest, calendar

I'm fairly new to SharePoint and have been wrestling with this particular problem for some time now. Whenever I try using the REST API for a calendar list using the following url

```
/<my_domain>//_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Class%20Sessions')/items?
```

it fails and returns the following:

```
 <m:error
 xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
 <m:code>-1, System.FormatException</m:code> <m:message
 xml:lang="en-US">Input string was not in a correct format.</m:message>
 </m:error>
```

The same format for all the rest of my lists that are non calendar type work just fine. I know I am not misspelling the list name and it does exist. I feel that there is something fundamentally wrong. Is there something special that I need to do for the calendar type list?

Any help to point me to the right direction will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `/_api/web/lists(guid'list GUID')`? Just for testing

Comment: If he title of the list contains a space you can leave it as ('Class Sessions') and will work.

Comment: Awesome! It work to perfection. Although I do wonder why it was a problem in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know what the problem was exactly but Cubanguy's suggestion worked just fine.
Instead of using the `getByTitle('ClassS')/fields` read operation I used `_api/web/lists(guid'<list id>')`.

It was a simple fix to an odd problem. Thank you!

Comment: I am facing the same issue, while i Use  rest to get a list data in my client web-part / App-Part in SP2013 i get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this scenario, and the problem was related to a incorrect Field definition.

Answer (score 1):

Late reply, but still may be useful for someone:

I've noticed %20 in input string - please be aware that SP marks spaces as '*x0020*', so 'Class_x0020_Sessions' should work.

TIP: Underscore is marked as '*x005f*'